# Plotting strings to table with gnuplot

Tags: string, gnuplot

It seems like when plotting to a table the string length of a column is apparently limited to about 62 characters.
The code below is a minimal example (gnuplot 5.2.5).

Why is the string length limited to such a "small" value? Is there a way around to be able to use longer strings?

```
### plot dataset to table including strings
reset session

$DataInput <<EOD
# tab separated data
1   0.123   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much for gnuplot.    84
2   0.456   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much.    72
3   0.789   This is some text, actually a lot of text.  42
EOD

set datafile commentschar ""
set datafile separator "\n"
set table $DataOutput
    plot $DataInput u (stringcolumn(1)) with table
unset table
set datafile separator "\t"
set datafile commentschar "#"

print "DataInput:"
print $DataInput

print "DataOutput:"
print $DataOutput

### end of code
```

Output:

```
DataInput:
# tab separated data
1   0.123   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much for gnuplot.    84
2   0.456   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much.    72
3   0.789   This is some text, actually a lot of text.  42

DataOutput:
 # tab separated data   
 1  0.123   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which appar
 2  0.456   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which appar
 3  0.789   This is some text, actually a lot of text.  42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found a bug, or at least an unnecessary limitation.  The per-column output length from "`plot with table`" is limited to the maximum width of the %g format, but that is irrelevant for strings.

Depending on the full use case you might be able to work around the bug by something based on "`plot with label`".  Here is an ugly example to be appended to the end of your sample code:

```
print "\ndirect output to table with labels"
set table $LabelOutput
    plot $DataInput using (0):(0):(stringcolumn(1)) with labels
unset table
print $LabelOutput

print "\n Edited version"
do for [i=1:|$LabelOutput|] {
    print $LabelOutput[i][1:1], $LabelOutput[i][7:*]
}
```

Output (yeah, the comments are mangled and I didn't remove the quotes):

```
direct output to table with labels

# Curve 0 of 1, 4 points
# Curve title: "$DataInput using (0):(0):(stringcolumn(1))"
# x y label type
 0  0 "# tab separated data"
 0  0 "1   0.123   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much for gnuplot.    84"
 0  0 "2   0.456   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much.    72"
 0  0 "3   0.789   This is some text, actually a lot of text.  42"



 Edited version

#e 0 of 1, 4 points
#e title: "$DataInput using (0):(0):(stringcolumn(1))"
#label type
 "# tab separated data"
 "1   0.123   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much for gnuplot.    84"
 "2   0.456   This is some text, actually a lot of text, which apparently is too much.    72"
 "3   0.789   This is some text, actually a lot of text.  42"
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I was not aware (or forgot) that you can directly iterate through the lines of a datablock by `do for [i=1:|$Data|] { print $Data[i] }` (or is it called dataset? I'm confused). Couldn't find this in `help`, where to find? This basically simplifies one of my intentions to replace strings in a dataset (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54541838/7295599) and with this plotting strings to a table is actually not needed anymore. So, in a sense question solved (or obsolete) :-) and a "bug" discovered ;-)